# How to get proper relationship between tables in merge statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, merge

There are two tables in database A.

Table 1:

people:

```
person_id,
row1,
row2
```

education:

```
education_id PK,
person_id FK,
row3,
row4
```

I want to merge this tables to database B. I use temp tables to save records, but there is a problem with pk key. In tables on database b, primary keys are auto-increment. How to remember a joins between tables in database b, so as to create the same joins but with new primary key numbers.
For example:
education

```
education_id person_id
1            3
2            5
3            8
```

First I used merge for people. Excellent all data was merged to database B, with new PK values. Now I want merge education table, but with the same relations(as in database A) to database B, but with new pk values. How to do it? I'm not sure that I explained the problem well. If there are any questions, ask them.

Comment: Just use a "staging" table between the source and the target. There you can maintain the relationship between the old and new primary keys, which will help you do your subsequent updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming that you have 2 temp tables INCLUDE source data

```
DECLARE @Person AS TABLE (personid int)

DECLARE @Education AS TABLE (educationid int, personid int)

DECLARE @MaxPersonId int ---- max Person ID in database B
```

You could do these steps to insert data into database B.
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Person ON` is the key to update

```
 -- 1. UPDATE temp table WITH new PersonId
UPDATE personid in temp Table
UPDATE @Person
SET
    personid = personid + @MaxPersonId

UPDATE @Education
SET
    personid = personid + @MaxPersonId

-- 2. INSERT person in to database B
-- SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Person ON would do the trick. 
-- You could insert a primary auto-increment field by a fixed value
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Person ON
  -- Insert person from temp table @Person
  INSERT INTO dbo.Person (PersonId) 
  SELECT p.personid FROM @Person p

 SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Person OFF

-- 3. INSERT INTO dbo.Education from @Education.
```